# 2007 MS Access - Report Button Creates Weird Background Image When Pop-Up Dialogue Box Does Not Cover the Button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a button in a MS Access 2007 report called 'Print'. The only event associated with this button is OnClick - PrintObject macro. When the button is clicked, the Print Dialog Box pops up. If the Dialog Box opens up such that it covers the button in the background, everything is great. However, if the Dialog Box opens up such that any part button shows, then after the report prints, a weird ghost image reflection of the button shows up behind the button and things that were behind the Dialog Box are all shifted around. I have attached an image showing the two scenarios. What is the problem here and how do I fix this?

[image]

When I add the 'Refresh' command to the programming for the OnClick, and run the 'Print' button, I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: The report is in ReportView so buttons can be clicked? But the actual paper printout is okay? What happens if you click the Refresh on ribbon?

Comment: Did this problem just start out of the blue, or is this a newly developed report? I would make a refresh of the report the last thing the OnClick event does. Also...even though Access allows it, I have never mixed form-type functionality with the reporting layer. The buttons should be on a form and the report should do just that and only that...report.

Comment: Actual paper printout is ok. If you click in the report or refresh the screen, it goes away. The report is a newly developed report.

Comment: I would like to make a refresh of the report the last thing the OnClick event does. I don't know how to do this. The only step in there now is RunMenuCommand --> PrintObject. If I add another step that is RunMenuCommand --> Refresh, I get an error. I will post that error in a minute, I just wanted to get this message out there into the world.

Comment: I added the Refresh error message to the post.